# Is there a faster way to test web apps for a mobile device?

Tags: iphone, testing, web, web-deployment

Currently I create my app on my Mac and then push the changes to heroku so that I can test the app on my phone. Is there a way I can test on the phone without having to push to heroku and thereby waiting for the build process to finish?

Comment: Does you web app need some sort of infrastructure that you can't host locally?

Comment: no, prod and dev are exactly the same.